# Como posso tirar o efeito de estilo da listView?

Tags: java, android, listview

Tenho um *layout*  e nele quero exibir os dados nessa `ListView` mas eu preciso que ela fique com fundo branco sem listras e sem click habilitado quando é tocada. Posso fazer dessa forma??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para remover a "listra" do seu `ListView` basta você definir o `divider` como `@null`. Veja abaixo:

```
<ListView 
  android:id="@+id/list"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:divider="@null" 
  android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>
```

E para que não tenha efeito no momento do `click`, basta você definir o `listSelector` como `transparent`.

```
<ListView 
      android:id="@+id/list"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:divider="@null" 
      android:dividerHeight="0dp"
      android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

Comment: UAU! Amanhã testarei no trabalho e te digo se funfou =D

Comment: Deu certo. Mas por que vc colocou o android:dividerHeight="0dp"?

Comment: @Aline para que o `divider` não tenha altura. Sendo assim, não sobra aquele espaço para o `divider`(aquela linha)

Comment: @Aline talvez em alguns aparelhos, definir somente o divider como `@null` não venha a funcionar, por isso por coloca `android:dividerHeight="0dp"`, que é a garantia de funcionar em qualquer dispositivo e qualquer versão do Android